# How can I connect to MongoDB server using JAVA from OpenShift?

Tags: java, mongodb, openshift, robo3t

I have created a `MongoDB` instance in `OpenShift`. I can connect to it via `RockMongo`, which is a service offered by `OpenShift`.

I'm trying to connect to my instance using `JAVA`, but I just receive a `Connection refuesed` error. Moreover, I cannot connect it using `RoboMongo`.

In my `RockMongo` status tab, I see the following information:

```
Host: 127.11.201.2
Port: 27017
```

Using `RoboMongo` with `MongoLab` instance works just fine giving it the right credentials, but here with `OpenShift` it fails on connecting to the instance.

In my `JAVA` app I'm trying the following:

```
MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(
                Const.MONGO_USERNAME, Cont.MONGO_DB,
                Const.MONGO_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        mongo = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(Const.MONGO_URI), Arrays.asList(credential));
```

With `127.11.201.2` as `MONGO_URI`.
Why am I failing to connect to my instance? What am I doing wrong?

P.S using `putty` I am able to connect to my `mongo` instance by just executing the command `mongo`.

Comment: Is there an error message of some sort?  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21859579/authentication-during-connection-to-mongodb-server-instance-using-java) suggest wrapping the `MongoCredential` in a `List<MongoCredential>`, then passing the list to the `MongoClient(...)` constructor.

Comment: It's a very strange behavior since I cannot connect using other tools like `RoboMongo`. I assume this is not a programmatic question after investigating it for a while now. But then again, I really don't know why my connection is being denied.

Comment: Yes but I got some port exceptions I need to figure out. I'll try it later on this week and keep you posted. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[OpenShift provides environment variables](https://developers.openshift.com/en/databases-mongodb.html), which you should use to connect to your MongoDB.

- `OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST` The MongoDB IP address
- `OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT` The MongoDB port
- `OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME` The MongoDB username
- `OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD` The MongoDB password
- `OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL` The MongoDB connection URL (e.g. `mongodb://<username>:<password>@<hostname>:<port>/`)

I'm using one line of code to connect to the database:

```
new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL")));
```

Comment: However, even when the vars come from a presumably safe source, they should be sanitized and not used unchecked.

Comment: Assumption: Somebody has managed to manipulate the generation of some or all needed environment vars, without gaining read access to the variables generated. I'd check wether the IP belongs to the expected range in order to prevent credentials to be sent to an unknown host. A forward and reverse lookup  and subsequent check if the values correspond. Next, it check wether the compound url matches the parts, is a valid URL and does not set unwanted connection parameters, such as an inappropriate write concern which might break SLAs.

Comment: A failure in one of those tests might indicate a security problem, be it an intended our accidental one.